# Unable to deploy docker image to GKE using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running the Jenkins jenkinsci/blueocean docker image on a Mac and am trying to build and deploy an image  to a Kubernetes cluster on GCP using a Jenkins pipeline (GKE plugin v0.8.3) but it fails --the image is built and added to the container registry (DockerHub) successfully but the deployment to GKE fails at the "Deploy to K8s" stage below .Jenkins does not display any error message. What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated

My deployment.yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mywebtestApp-deployment
  labels:
    app: mywebtestApp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mywebtestApp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mywebtestApp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mywebtestApp
        image: <mydockerhub>/<myimagename>:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and my Jenkins file

```
pipeline {
    agent any   
    environment {
............
  stage('Deploy to K8s') { 
                steps{
                   echo 'Deployment started ...'
                 step([$class: 'KubernetesEngineBuilder', projectId: env.PROJECT_ID, clusterName: env.CLUSTER_NAME, location: env.LOCATION, manifestPattern: 'deployment.yaml', credentialsId: env.CREDENTIALS_ID, verifyDeployments: true])
           echo "Deployment Finished ..."
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will apply this `Deployment` on your cluster you will get error:

```
The Deployment "mywebtestApp-deployment" is invalid:
 * metadata.name: Invalid value: "mywebtestApp-deployment": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
 * spec.template.spec.containers[0].name: Invalid value: "mywebtestApp": a DNS-1123 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')
```

You cannot use capital letters.

You have to change your labels from `app: mywebtestApp` to app: mywebtestapp and `deployment` name from `name: mywebtestApp-deployment` to `name: mywebtestApp-deployment`

After that changes you will be able to create `deployment`.

```
$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
deployment.apps/mywebtestapp-deployment created
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The uppercase letter and an indentation issue  were causing the issue.